# How to create a webservice in google cloud using nodeJs and expose storage browser folder contains html, js, image files to the client?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform

I am having a situation here, where I have all my code in the storage browser in google cloud. The idea is to create a nodeJs webservice in app Engine and expose the folders which consists of html, js and image files. Such that user can access the site using those files. Hope am able to explain my situation. Is it possible, if so please help

Thanks

Comment: I think what you are saying is that you have created a Google Cloud Storage (GCS) bucket which contains "folders" that contain "files" that correspond to HTML, JS and images and you want to serve those directly to a browser?  If yes, then see the following article ... https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public and https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-public-data

Comment: yes you are right.. thanks for the comments. Will check the link. Happy holidays

Comment: I want this Cloud Storage url to be not visible, because exposing the url can be prone to attacks. So, if I have nodeJs service in app engine I can use firewall setup and then make it secure and avoid any vulnerabilities and access the files from bucket

Comment: do you want to have a static website? nothing executing on the server side. if that is what you want you can check [this](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/web-serving-overview#static-site) where it describes how to do it.

Comment: Yes, we want a static website exposed via app engine. Please help. We can't directly expose storage bucket since there are no firewall rules on storage bucket. Storage bucket can limit only user access and not by IP address.

Comment: Why not just deploy an static web in app engine then?

Comment: Agreed... But, one quick thing how do we manage multiple environments or streams. We have A/B testing on our end. Per my knowledge we can only have one app engine defined, how can we have multiple environments served. Do I have to create a new api let's say I use nodejs for each environment(with different ports). There comes one more question we have to include cicd process using Jenkins. Any sample documentation for cicd. Every service we run while we deploy the code also requires a backup plan to restart when google cloud goes a reboot. Any scripts then can do cron jobs. Sorry too many asks

Comment: on app engine you can easily deploy new version and migrate the traffic between them, you can do a/b testing or canary testing easily: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java11/migrating-traffic

Comment: Thanks all for the support, this will help me to start my poc. Really appreciate your inputs. Happy Holidays

Answer (score 1):

You can Deploy static websites directly on Google Cloud Storage. If what stops you to do it is that the URL of the bucket will be exposed or because you want to use your custom domain having one can will solve the issue.

On the domain registrar just add a record type CNAME to `c.storage.googleapis.com`

[here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website) you can see this more explained.

Also to limit the access to certain files in the bucket you can use [ACLs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/create-manage-lists) to control the access on a file per file basis.